# Location of friend as a notification

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, notifications

FriendFinder is an application integrated with Google Maps that will help you and your friends find each other no matter where you are. You can choose which friends can find you then fire off your location with just the click of a button; instantly your friends know exactly where to meet up with you AND they have a map with driving, walking, or public transportation directions.

I am trying to make this application myself but the thing is that I am unable to do a part where the locator knows his friends position with a click on friends button . My main question is How to send the notification of location of friend to the locator . I want any source code or any tutorials for notificatins from one android mobile to another .

The other parts like google map view navigation , reverse geocoding I have done .Only getting the friend's longitute lattude is the problem I am facing .

Sudhanshu

Comment: This sounds quite a bit like Google Latitude, which is already part of the Google Maps Android app: http://www.google.com/mobile/latitude/

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a push service, so you can push "informations" to other android devices.

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is a good way to do this.

http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

hope this helps.